# How to change the default width and height of a dialog in Magnolia 5.3?

Tags: magnolia

I need to change the default width and height of a dialog. I have tried in a way, that i have added two properties width, height to my dialog.But still not updated with the given width and height. Could you please suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

Dialog width is 720px by default. To open a dialog in wide mode, set the `wide` property to `true` in the [dialog definition](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Dialog+definition#Dialogdefinition-Dialogproperties). The dialog then uses all available horizontal space. The user can toggle between normal and wide modes by clicking the expand/collapse button in the top right corner.

Dialog height automatically adapts to fit the contents. You cannot set a fixed height. However, some form fields such as [text](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Text+field) and rich text allow you to set a height so you have some control over the height of the dialog.